# GMock EXPECT_CALL of an overloaded function with abstract argument type

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a code like that below, but I can't figure out how to install an EXPECT_CALL on the subscribe function (without a specific instance). If I use `_` than it can not resolve which function is meant and if I use a `Matcher<I1>(_)` it tells me that an instance of an abstract class can't be created.

```
class I1{
    virtual void get()=0;
};
class I2{
    virtual void get()=0;
};
class Testee {
virtual void subscribe(I1&);
virtual void subscribe(I2&);

EXPECT_CALL(TesteeObj,subscribe(_));
EXPECT_CALL(TesteeObj,subscribe(Matcher<I1>(_)));
```

Comment: I can't find a duplicate quickly, but you need a typed wildcard: `EXPECT_CALL(TesteeObj,subscribe(::testing::A<I1&>()));`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I also was not able to find a duplicate, that's why I ask. :-)

Comment: I only found it because I remembered answering such question before ;) Glad it helped.